# Scene Kit: Use multiple SCNView instances side by side

Tags: ios, opengl-es, scenekit, metal

For a panorama viewing application, I'd like to show multiple panoramas side-by-side inside a UICollectionView. The single panoramas are represented as cube-mapped textures. The rendering is done using Scene Kit.

When using a single SCNView, the application performs fine. When I instantiate multiple SCNViews side by side, the frame rate for all SCNViews plummets to almost one frame per second. GPU and CPU utilisation is almost zero.

The arrangement of the single SCNViews can be seen below:

[image: Arrangement of the SCNViews]

I observed that each SCNView spawns a separate render thread. The problem persists regardless of weather OpenGL or Metal is used as render API.

How could we resolve or at least debug this issue?

Comment: Are these live, active scenes with changing elements? If nothing is moving, you'll see extreme optimization from SceneKit, to save power. It won't be spinning at 60 FPS to redraw static content. What do you expect to be happening, and what is happening instead?

Comment: They are constantly moving - we move the panoramas whenever the device is moved (via CoreMotion). 
We'd it to run smoothly with 30-60 fps, but the frame rate drops very low and the UI lags a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using child nodes instead of additional SCNViews?

Comment: This is definitely the right approach—having multiple OpenGL or Metal views animating at once is a recipe for calamitous performance. Use one view and draw multiple things in it.

Comment: How would you do that in combination with UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: The problem is exactly the UICollectionView. 

Using UICollectionView requires having a bunch of distinct UI elements. I assume there is no way to use the same GLContext and render thread for several UI elements?

Comment: You can reuse the same GL context / Metal resources for multiple SceneKit renderers (see [`SCNRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNRenderer_Class/)), but ultimately that GL/Metal workflow must render in a single view. A collection view's cells are multiple views, so that doesn't help much. (Also, multiple `SCNRenderer`s are at least as heavyweight as multiple GL/Metal contexts.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of UICollectionView, how about using a SpriteKit scene?

SpriteKit scene is tiled with a collection of square/rectangular `SK3DNode` instances. Each node has one panorama, rendered using a SceneKit scene as you're doing now with the UICV cells.

Comment: This would have the advantage of combining all rendering into the same GL / Metal context. You'd lose the 2d layout features of `UICollectionView`, though. Perhaps an interesting (but cumbersome) hybrid approach would be using a `UICollectionView` of invisible elements to handle layout, and an `SKView` containing `SK3DNode`s to handle rendering — where you manually sync the frames of the invisible collection view elements with the SpriteKit elements responsible for rendering.